# PHP image upload: Transparency showing up as a black

Tags: javascript, php, image, transparency

I'm very new to PHP and I don't really understand how to fix a common bug. When I upload a png using the following code the background shows up as black. There are some solutions out there which show how to fix it but I don't know where to put it in the code and everything I find breaks it. I'm using this code:

```
<?php
############ Configuration ##############
$destination_folder     = '../img/'; //upload directory ends with / (slash)
##########################################

//continue only if $_POST is set and it is a Ajax request
if(isset($_POST) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){


$whichimage = $_POST["whichimage"];

// check $_FILES['ImageFile'] not empty
if(!isset($_FILES['image_file']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'])){
        die('Image file is Missing!'); // output error when above checks fail.
}

//uploaded file info we need to proceed
$image_name = $_FILES['image_file']['name']; //file name
$image_temp = $_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name']; //file temp

$image_size_info    = getimagesize($image_temp); //get image size

if($image_size_info){
    $image_type         = $image_size_info['mime']; //image type
}else{
    die("Make sure image file is valid!");
}

//switch statement below checks allowed image type
//as well as creates new image from given file
switch($image_type){
    case 'image/png':
        $image_res =  imagecreatefrompng($image_temp); break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $image_res =  imagecreatefromgif($image_temp); break;
    case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
        $image_res = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_temp); break;
    default:
        $image_res = false;
}

if($image_res){
    //Get file extension and name to construct new file name
    $image_info = pathinfo($image_name);
    $image_extension = strtolower($image_info["extension"]); //image extension
    $image_name_only = strtolower($image_info["filename"]);//file name only, no extension

    //create a name for new image (Eg: fileName_293749.jpg) ;
    $new_file_name = $whichimage . '.' . $image_extension;

    //folder path to save resized images and thumbnails

    $image_save_folder  = $destination_folder . $new_file_name;

    //call normal_resize_image() function to proportionally resize image
    if(normal_resize_image($image_res, $image_save_folder, $image_type))
    {

    }

    imagedestroy($image_res); //freeup memory
}
}

#####  This function will proportionally resize image #####
function normal_resize_image($source, $destination, $image_type){

//do not resize if image is smaller than max size
    if(save_image($source, $destination, $image_type)){
        return true;
    }


}

##### Saves image resource to file #####
function save_image($source, $destination, $image_type){
switch(strtolower($image_type)){//determine mime type
    case 'image/png':
        imagepng($source, $destination); return true; //save png file
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        imagegif($source, $destination); return true; //save gif file
        break;
    case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
        imagejpeg($source, $destination); return true; //save jpeg file
        break;
    default: return false;
}
}
```

[Which is a modified and stripped down version from this tutorial](http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/05/ajax-image-upload-and-resize-with-jquery-and-php/)

I don't want to re-size the images and change the quality so I tried removing those parts of the code.

In the comment section of the tutorial though there are a few posts about fixing the transparency with this:

```
imagealphablending($NewCanves, false);
imagesavealpha($NewCanves,true);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($NewCanves, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefilledrectangle($NewCanves, 0, 0, $NewWidth, $NewHeight, $transparent);
```

But the problem is those snippits go into the removed image re-size section.

How do I properly fix the transparency issues with my modified code?
Thanks for reading and helping a PHP noob.

Comment: if you're not doing any resizing, then why bother with GD at all? just `move_uploaded_file()` so the original uploaded file gets preserved as-is.

Comment: Well I do have to have the ability to convert some images from png to jpeg and gif to jpeg later on. Does that change this?

Comment: yes, jpg doesn't have transparency, and gif only supports single color transparency. converting png to either will LOSE most/all of the transparancy info

Comment: Oh no I know sorry! Only some of the photos will be converted to jpg. I'm working on trying to get a logo png to upload with transparency.

Comment: you don't have to do anything server-side, then. it can't add transparency to an image that didn't already have it. e.g. you have to upload a transparent png to start with.

Comment: Hmm. Would I still be able to rename the file to say "logo.png". This form is for uploading 7 different images and it grabs what to rename it to from a html form. How would I implement both so that only the logo went through    move_uploaded_file() ?

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['whateveryoucalledit']['tmp_name'], '/path/to/filenamethatyouspecify')`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after taking a break and feeling really dumb! Thanks again to Marc B for your thoughts. The solution I went with was as follows:

Adding the following lines:

```
imagealphablending($image_res, false);
imagesavealpha($image_res, true);
```

To this part of the code:

```
//switch statement below checks allowed image type
//as well as creates new image from given file
switch($image_type){
    case 'image/png':
        $image_res =  imagecreatefrompng($image_temp); imagealphablending($image_res, false);
        imagesavealpha($image_res, true); break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $image_res =  imagecreatefromgif($image_temp); break;
    case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
        $image_res = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_temp); break;
    default:
        $image_res = false;
}
```